# Import data from Salesforce Report using ADF

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am working on importing data from Salesforce Report using ADF. I am using **copy activity** and have created **salesforce linked service**.

I did get the below syntax from Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce but I get the below error.

[image]

**Error:**

> Failed to import source schema. ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (120) SOQL_FIRST mode prepare failure: SOQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near '"<<< ??? >>>query": "{call "Quality & Impact Survey Results by Tier"}"'. SQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near '"query"<<< ??? >>>: "{call "Reportname"}"'. Activity ID: a1373279-97e4-42e4-86e3-80d930ef9364

If anyone have worked on this then do let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the syntax to extract data from Salesforce from ADF as per below.

**{call "Reportname"}**

[image]